# Magento 2: How to use constructor injection in Contoller

Tags: magento2, controllers, dependency-injection

I've following controller code which is working fine using object manager. How I can use constructor injection instead of object manager for this ?

```
namespace Amit\Qr\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory  */

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory

    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
        $order->load($orderId);
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
        echo $customerId;
        //.....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move all dependencies to constructor

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory  */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    private $orderFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory

    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = $this->orderFactory->create();
        $order->load($orderId);
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
        echo $customerId;
        //.....
   }
}
```

next step will be use Services:

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory  */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository */
    private $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository

    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
        echo $customerId;
        //.....
   }
}
```

Comment: Controller code works. How I can use it with services?

Comment: After add dependencies You should remove **var/generation** folder

Answer (score 2):

You have to inject Model Order by [Factories](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/factories.html)

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
    .....another injection......
) {
    $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    ....
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute() {
     $order = $this->orderFactory->create(); // Use Factory to create instance order model object
}
```

Try to avoid use directly `_objectManager` as much as possible